# Continuous CSS effect onClick and hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hover on red button. I want this hover effect until removing the mouse. Another: While click on green button, it will keep it's click style.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#color1").hover(function() {
    $(".bg-img").css({
      "background-image": "url('assets/img/black.png')"
    });
  }, function() {
    $(".bg-img").css({
      "background-image": "url('assets/img/SMF98.png')"
    });
  });

  $('#color2').click(function() {
    $(".bg-img").css({
      "background-image": "url('assets/img/green.png')"
    });
    $('#color2').addClass("Blink");
  });

  $('#color3').click(function() {
    $(".bg-img").css({
      "background-image": "url('assets/img/red.png')"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.bg-img {
  background-image: url("assets/img/SMF98.png");
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

.hovicon {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 90px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
}

.hovicon.small {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 7px;
}

.hovicon.mini {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 32px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 7px;
}

.hovicon.auto-width {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

.hovicon:after {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.hovicon:before {
  speak: none;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 90px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: block;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.hovicon.effect-2 {
  color: #eea303;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #000;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.3s;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}

.hovicon.effect-2:after {
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  padding: 2px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
}

.color2.effect-2:after {
  background: green!important;
}

.color2.effect-2 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px green;
}

.color3.effect-2:after {
  background: darkred!important;
}

.color3.effect-2 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px darkred;
}


/* Effect 2a */

.hovicon.effect-2.sub-a:hover,
.hovicon.effect-2.sub-a:hover i {
  color: #eea303;
}

.hovicon.effect-2.sub-a:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.85);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.85);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.85);
  transform: scale(0.85);
}


/* Effect 2b */

.hovicon.effect-2.sub-b:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.2s;
}

.hovicon.effect-2.sub-b:hover,
.hovicon.effect-2.sub-b:hover i {
  color: #fff;
}

.navigation-clean-button .action-button,
.navigation-clean-button .action-button:active {
  background: #56c6c6!important;
  border-radius: 20px!important;
  font-size: inherit!important;
  color: #fff!important;
  box-shadow: none!important;
  border: none!important;
  text-shadow: none!important;
  padding: .5rem 1rem!important;
  transition: background-color 0.25s!important;
  font-size: inherit!important;
}

.navigation-clean-button .actions {
  margin-top: 1px!important;
  padding-top: 0!important;
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem!important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .row1 {
    display: list-item;
  }
  .hovicon {
    margin: 20px 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
  }
}

.Blink {
  animation: blinker 1.5s cubic-bezier(.5, 0, 1, 1) infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


/* Effect 8 */

.hovicon.effect-8 {
  background: red;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform ease-out 0.1s, background 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform ease-out 0.1s, background 0.2s;
  transition: transform ease-out 0.1s, background 0.2s;
}

.hovicon.effect-8:after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.9);
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

.hovicon.effect-8:hover {
  background: red;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.93);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.93);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.93);
  transform: scale(0.93);
  color: #fff;
}

.hovicon.effect-8:hover i {
  color: #fff;
}

.hovicon.effect-8:hover:after {
  -webkit-animation: sonarEffect 1.3s ease-out 75ms;
  -moz-animation: sonarEffect 1.3s ease-out 75ms;
  animation: sonarEffect 1.3s ease-out 75ms;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sonarEffect {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 0 10px 10px #3851bc, 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 0 10px 10px #3851bc, 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes sonarEffect {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 0 10px 10px #3851bc, 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 0 10px 10px #3851bc, 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes sonarEffect {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 0 10px 10px #3851bc, 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 0 10px 10px #3851bc, 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=ABeeZee">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aclonica">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alex+Brush">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allan">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amaranth">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amita">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,700,700i">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:300,400|Roboto:300,400,700">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans">

<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand fixed-bottom bg-dark navbar-fixed-top navigation-clean-button">
  <div class="container-fluid"><button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1"></button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">

      <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-lg-11 col-xl-11 col-8">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-1 col-xl-5"></div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-10 col-xl-4">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-4 col-xl-4">
                  <span id="color1">
                                            <div class="block">
                                                <div class="hovicon effect-2 sub-a color1"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </span>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-4 col-xl-4">
                  <span id="color2">
                                            <div class="block">
                                                <div class="hovicon effect-2 sub-a color2"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </span>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-4 col-xl-4">
                  <span id="color3">
                                            <div class="block">
                                                <div class="hovicon effect-8 sub-a color3"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-1 col-xl-3"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-4">
        <p class="ml-auto float-right navbar-text actions">
          <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg action-button" role="button" href="https://www.myaurochs.com/product/infinity/" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse" style="background-color:#2ec56a;">Buy Now</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
<section>
  <div class="bg-img">

  </div>
  <!--<img src="assets/img/SMF98.png" class="bg-img" width="100%">-->
</section>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qsc206v7/2/

Comment: The full content of your question must be in your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to create one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: How can I show CSS problem without link??? Can't paste a long code. You should not be crazy.

Comment: Of course you can. Use a snippet.

Comment: I tried for some times, So I give in this way.

Comment: I'm so 'crazy' I edited the code in to the question for you. I also fixed the snippet as you'd forgotten to include jQuery and instead included a ton of local references which broke the logic. Please remember to add actual code to the questions in future

Comment: ha ha ha.... Thank you for your edit and time.. I will remember your great suggestions.

Comment: What is "this hover effect" you are talking about?

Comment: I can't get which part you means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution to the red circle

It is not possible to add a class via Javascript to a pseudo-element (for the green circle) so you would have to come up with an alternative method.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.hovicon {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 90px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
}

.hovicon:after {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.hovicon:before {
  speak: none;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 90px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: block;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}


/* Effect 8 */

.hovicon.effect-8 {
  background: red;
  transition: transform ease-out 0.1s, background 0.2s;
}

.hovicon.effect-8:after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

.hovicon.effect-8:hover {
  background: red;
  transform: scale(0.93);
  color: #fff;
}

.hovicon.effect-8:hover i {
  color: #fff;
}

.hovicon.effect-8:hover:after {
  animation: sonarEffect 1.3s ease-out 75ms infinite;
}

@keyframes sonarEffect {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 0 10px 10px #3851bc, 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 0 10px 10px #3851bc, 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hovicon effect-8 sub-a color3"></div>
```

---

## Solution to the green circle

For the green circle I made a new div inside with the styling to resemble the white circle with `display: none;` and with jQuery toggle the `display` on click.

```js
$(".green").click(function(){
 $(".innerCircle").toggleClass("show");
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.green {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}

.innerCircle {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid white;
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="green">
  <div class="innerCircle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.
You can try for green button again. Please.

Comment: Or If it is not possible to do how can I differentiate selected!! Suggested me because you saw my code. Again Thanks.

Comment: I made a working solution for the green circle too. I updated my answer so you can find it there. Hope you like it :)

Comment: It's really great. Thanks a lot. Correct ans.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this in your hover css

```
whatever:hover{
       animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```